# How do I pass in an argument to a list of lambdas?

Tags: python, lambda, filtering, list-comprehension

Intent: I'm trying to return each dictionary that contains the passed in matching keywords and values within a list of dictionaries. For example, `a='woot', e='1', c='duh'` would return only

```
{'a': 'woot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'duh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '1'}
```

This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to pass in an argument to a list of lambda expression which act as the filter for each dictionary in the list.

```
sample_dict = [
{'a': 'woot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'duh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '1'},
{'a': 'coot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'ruh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '2'},
{'a': 'doot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'suh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '3'},
{'a': 'soot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'fuh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '4'},
{'a': 'toot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'cuh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '1'}
]


def get_matched_lines(input_dict, **param):
    filters = [lambda input_dict_elem,
                      input_key=param_key,
                      input_value=param_value:
               input_dict_elem[input_key] == input_value
               for param_key, param_value in param.items()]
    return [dict_elem for dict_elem in input_dict if(all(filters))]

print(get_matched_lines(sample_dict, a='woot', e='1', c='duh'))
```

Comment: does this code not work or does it give error?

Comment: This code is functional, but it returns all the dictionaries in the list. The intent is only to return the dictionaries in the list that match the passed in keywords and values. I've edited the description to make it a little clearer.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: from the code it looks like its Python 3

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this (in Python 2.7):

```
def get_matched_lines(input_dict, **param):
    return [dic for dic in input_dict if all([key in dic and dic[key] == val for key, val in param.iteritems()])]
```

The same code in Python 3 is

```
def get_matched_lines(input_dict, **param):
    return [dic for dic in input_dict if all([key in dic and dic[key] == val for key, val in param.items()])]
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I'm just gonna post a Python3 answer which is just switching out iteritems() with items().

Comment: [dic for dic in sample_dict if all([key in dic and dic[key] == val for key, val in param.items()])]

Comment: you're welcome :-) the Python 3 version is already edited in.

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around it but I think I understand it! Thank you again! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_matched_lines(input_dict, array):
    output=[]
    keys=[]
    values=[]
    for a in array:
        keyvalue = a.split("=")
        keys.append(keyvalue[0]) 
        values.append(keyvalue[1])   
    for dict in input_dict:
        bool=1
        for i in range(0,len(keys)):
            if keys[i] in dict.keys():
                # print values[i]
                if dict[keys[i]] != values[i]:
                    bool=0
        if bool==1:
            output.append(dict)
    return output


sample_dict = [
{'a': 'woot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'duh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '1'},
{'a': 'coot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'ruh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '2'},
{'a': 'doot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'suh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '3'},
{'a': 'soot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'fuh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '4'},
{'a': 'toot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'cuh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '1'}
]
array = ["a=woot", "e=1", "c=duh"]
print get_matched_lines(sample_dict, array)
```

output:

```
[{'a': 'woot', 'c': 'duh', 'b': 'nope', 'e': '1', 'd': 'rough'}]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this by using a list of lambda expressions to filter the list of dictionaries? This way using a nested for loop will work but I wanted to avoid using a nested loop by using all() with a list of lambda expressions. Is it even possible?

Comment: Well, i don't know about that

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use lambda here... basic for loop is enough...

Concept is simple as the following:
If all the keys and values in param belongs and equals to the input_dict, it returns the whole dictionary row which you want to return. If at least a key can't be found or a value isn't the same, return nothing.

```
sample_dict = [
{'a': 'woot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'duh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '1'},
{'a': 'coot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'ruh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '2'},
{'a': 'doot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'suh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '3'},
{'a': 'soot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'fuh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '4'},
{'a': 'toot', 'b': 'nope', 'c': 'cuh', 'd': 'rough', 'e': '1'}
]


def get_matched_lines(input_dict, **param):
    return [d_ for d_ in sample_dict if all([False for k in param if not k in d_ or d_[k]!=param[k]])]

print(get_matched_lines(sample_dict, a='woot', e='1', c='duh'))
```

More question, then let me know.